# Stub method with instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, stub

Lets say I have a controller: `UserController`

and there is a method:

```
before_action :add_friend

def add_friend
   @friend = Friend.last
end
```

How can I stub `add_friend` and create instead another instance_variable called `@friend2`:

```
@friend2 = Friend.first
```

So that:

```
@friend == nil
```

and

```
@friend2.nil? == false
```

What I tried was:

```
 @friend2 = Friend.first
 UserController.any_instance.stubs(:add_friend).returns(@friend2)
```

But that didnt worked! **Thanks**

Comment: Which Rspec version?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed I am using Rspec 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
describe UsersController, "..." do
  before(:each) do
    @friend2 = Friend.first
    controller.stub!(:add_friend).and_return(@friend2)
  end
  ...
  ...
end
```

Comment: In this case you don't have to make it an instance variable